# TypeORMError: Entity metadata for x#y was not found

Tags: typescript, nestjs, entity, metadata, typeorm

I stuck in here. **TypeORMError: Entity metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.**
My *database.config.ts*

```
export default {
  type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  // entities: [path.resolve('dist/modules/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}')],
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
  extra: {
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
};
```

My *vendorModule.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { VendorController } from './controllers/vendor.controller';
import { Vendor } from './entities/vendor.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { CqrsModule } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { AdminVendorController } from './controllers/admin-vendor.controller';
import { CrmVendorController } from './controllers/crm-vendor.controller';
import { PublicVendorController } from './controllers/public-vendor.controller';
import { SecretVendorController } from './controllers/secret-vendor.controller';
import { TokenService } from 'src/common/services/token.service';
import { TruckCategory } from '@modules/truck-category/entities/truck-category.entity';
import { TruckCategoryModule } from '@modules/truck-category/truck-category.module';
import { VendorService } from './services/vendor.service';
import { Slugs } from './entities/slug.entity';
import { UserService } from '@common/services/user.service';
import { CompanyService } from '@common/services/company.service';
import { TruckSize } from '@modules/truck-size/entities/truck-size.entity';
import { TruckSizeModule } from '@modules/truck-size/truck-size.module';
import { CrmHistory } from './entities/crm-history';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      Vendor,
      Slugs,
      TruckCategory,
      TruckSize,
      CrmHistory,
    ]),
    TruckSizeModule,
    TruckCategoryModule,
    HttpModule,
    CqrsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    VendorController,
    AdminVendorController,
    CrmVendorController,
    PublicVendorController,
    SecretVendorController,
  ],
  providers: [VendorService, TokenService, UserService, CompanyService],
  exports: [VendorService],
})
export class VendorModule {}
```

My *crm-history.ts* entity is

```
import { AbstractEntity } from '@common/abstract-entity';
import { Column, Entity, Index, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { Vendor } from './vendor.entity';

export interface crmType {
  userId: string;
  role: string;
}

@Entity('vendor_crm_histories')
export class CrmHistory extends AbstractEntity {
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    unique: true,
  })
  kam: crmType;

  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    unique: true,
  })
  clusterHead: crmType;

  @ManyToOne(() => Vendor, (vendor) => vendor.crmHistories)
  vendor: Vendor;
}
```

my *vendor.ts* entity

```
import { AbstractEntity } from 'src/common/abstract-entity';
import { Column, Entity, Index, JoinColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import {
  Gender,
  MakePayoutDay,
  SubscriptionType,
  VendorStatus,
} from '../enums';
import { OriginDistrictsDto } from '../dtos/create-vendor.dto';
import { TruckCategory } from '@modules/truck-category/entities/truck-category.entity';
import { TruckSize } from '@modules/truck-size/entities/truck-size.entity';
import { UserType } from '@common/decorators/user.decorator';
import { Slugs } from './slug.entity';
import { CrmHistory } from './crm-history';
@Entity('vendors')
export class Vendor extends AbstractEntity {
  @Index({ unique: true })
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    unique: true,
  })
  userId: string; //vendor userId is given automatically from user service.
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    default: '',
  })
  fullName: string; //vendor's full name
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
  })
  email: string; //vendor's email address
  @Index({ unique: true })
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: false,
    unique: true,
  })
  phone: string; //vendor's unique phone number
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
    default: null,
  })
  profilePicture: string;
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'boolean',
    nullable: false,
    default: false,
  })
  isEnabled: boolean;
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'boolean',
    nullable: false,
    default: false,
  })
  isVerified: boolean;
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: false,
    default: 'vendor',
  })
  role: string; //vendor's role is vendor.
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'jsonb',
    nullable: false,
    default: {},
  })
  originDistrict: OriginDistrictsDto;
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
  })
  tln: string;
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
  })
  companyName: string;
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    nullable: true,
  })
  companyAddress: string;
  @Column({
    type: 'jsonb',
    nullable: false,
    default: {},
  })
  assignKam: UserType; // assignee should be vendor team member(kam)
  @Column({
    type: 'jsonb',
    nullable: false,
    default: {},
  })
  assignCluster: UserType; // assignee should be vendor team member(kam)
  @Column({
    type: 'integer',
    nullable: false,
    default: 0,
  })
  vehicleProvide: number;
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: MakePayoutDay,
    nullable: false,
    default: MakePayoutDay.MONDAY,
  })
  makePayout: MakePayoutDay;
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: SubscriptionType,
    nullable: false,
    default: SubscriptionType.BRONZE,
  })
  subsType: SubscriptionType;
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Gender,
    nullable: false,
    default: Gender.MALE,
  })
  gender: Gender;
  @Index()
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: VendorStatus,
    nullable: false,
    default: VendorStatus.ACTIVE,
  })
  status: VendorStatus; //vendor availability.
  @OneToMany(() => TruckCategory, (cat) => cat.vendor)
  @JoinColumn()
  truckCategories: TruckCategory[];
  @OneToMany(() => TruckSize, (size) => size.vendor)
  @JoinColumn()
  truckSizes: TruckSize[];
  @OneToMany(() => Slugs, (slug) => slug.vendor)
  @JoinColumn()
  slugs: Slugs[];
  @OneToMany(() => CrmHistory, (crmHistories) => crmHistories.vendor)
  @JoinColumn()
  crmHistories: CrmHistory[];
}
```

my error are

> ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying
> (1)... TypeORMError: Entity metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not
> found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's
> connected in the connection options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:19 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:23 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (3)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:26 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (4)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:30 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (5)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:33 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (6)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:37 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (7)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:40 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (8)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:44 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable
> to connect to the database. Retrying (9)... TypeORMError: Entity
> metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified
> a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection
> options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)
> [Nest] 11704  - 08/27/2022, 9:58:44 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler]
> Entity metadata for Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you
> specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the
> connection options. TypeORMError: Entity metadata for
> Vendor#crmHistories was not found. Check if you specified a correct
> entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
> at /home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
> at DataSource.buildMetadatas (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:670:13)
> at DataSource.initialize (/home/loop-pc/loop/loop-supplier/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:242:13)

if i remove the crm entity, it works fine as it before. I have created several tables just before one day. But this entity shows me this kinda error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't named my files properly. Those are without like `crm-history.ts` where I should write like `crm-history.entity.ts`